# Is "Which test or tests would you give him to do" considered a correct sentence?

Tags: style

Because I'm not a native English speaker, I have a habit before I publish a sentence: I google it to see its frequency in the world.

In this case I just googled the words:

> "would you give him"

which I took from the sentence: "Which test or tests would you give him to do?" I only got 8 results, so now I suspect this might not be a correct sentence.

Comment: By the way, Google results for such a phrase are no indication of its validity. At least try an ngram search.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+you+give+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20you%20give%20him%3B%2Cc0  And even that doesn't necessarily prove anything.

Comment: I wonder how come you got only 8 results of `"would you give him"`. I did a quick try and found lots of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

Depending on context, you probably don't need the "to do" at the end. Most of the time, when you 'give' someone a test, it means that you administer it to them, which is correspondingly phrased as them 'taking' the test.

Also, "test or tests" is pretty formal, so in most situations I would drop "test or". When you ask "which [plural noun]", you're basically asking for a list of things as a response. Someone can respond with a list of just one.

So, I would ask:

> **Question:** Which tests would you give him?

And might expect these sort of answers:

> **Singular answer:** Just this one.
>   **Plural answer:** These three.

Comment: Thank you deeply for you comment.
By the way,take into account that I talked about laboratory tests (blood test, urine test etc)

Comment: @Dory I don't think that that significantly changes anything. You might go ahead and include "test or tests" in that setting to be careful not to imply that the patient should receive more tests than necessary. You definitely don't need "to do", as no one is going to interpret 'give' as 'transferring ownership' when you're talking about giving tests to a patient.